# $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|\tan x|}{x}=$?

Tags: limits

I was doing this math today:

Q) $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|\tan x|}{x}=$?

(a) 1

(b) -1

(c) 0

(d) Does not exist

I know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan x}{x}=1$, so I thought that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|\tan x|}{x}=1$ as well. But this is wrong. [If we see the graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gunwemi3nm), it becomes sufficiently clear to us that the limit does not exist:

[image]

After I see a graph, I can tell whether the limit exists or not. My question is that how will I know if a limit exists or not in the exam hall when I don't have access to desmos?

Comment: You should not be relying on Desmos or any other computer program to learn mathematics. Believe it or not, people were doing mathematics before there were computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a absolute value, the best way is computing the two directional limits:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\vert \tan x\vert}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\tan x}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1+\tan^2 x}{1}=1$$
In the other hand
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{\vert \tan x\vert}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{-\tan x}{x}=-1$$
Since they differ, the limit does not exist. You can also see this in the graph of the function. In the exam, for a function like this, its credible to draw an easy draw of the graph to orientate you